# Rosewill RSV-S5 and WIndows Server 2008 RC2 Software Raid

Tags: software-raid, storage

I have just bought a Rosewill RSV-S5 http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816132015 because i want to move the hardisks out of my case.
I have 5 disks now in a software raid 5, made in Windows Server 2008 RC2.

My question is can i move the disks over to the Rosewill RSV-S5 and keep my data, or do i need to backup all my data first and recreate the raid once they have been installed in Rosewill RSV-S5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it the enclosure has it's own RAID controller. If this is the case, it is very unlikely that it will be able to read the RAID configuration used by Windows and you will have to backup and then re-create the array. I would always recommend backing up before doing this sort of thing anyway.

Also, I hope your using Server 2008 R2, and not RC2, the release candidate expired a long time ago!